# Dimension too large

Tags: beamer

After adding a couple of slides to a beamer presentation I am having the error below. Everything was fine, and suddenly I had that. The presentation has 45 slides and is mostly figures (pdf, via `graphicx`), boxes (via `tcolorbox`), and some text.

```
! Dimension too large. <recently
read> \pgfmath@x
```

I cannot add the MWE because I have many slides. I believe (not sure) that it is related width the presentation size.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: There are so many ways this can happen, the information is insufficient.

Comment: You *can* add an MWE. But your MWE cannot consist of your entire document. That isn't a problem because it wouldn't be an MWE in that case. It is extremely unlikely this is due to the size of the presentation. TeX is complaining about a *dimension* being too large. That's something you've added causing it.

Comment: Put `\end{document}` after your first frame. If that doesn't cause the error move to the next until it does and remove the previous ones. If it does give the error you have the MWE already.

Comment: Well I don't know where the problem comes from. And it is too big my document to add here. However, now I changed the style to simple and it worked. The original style uses `tikz` to \draw a counter. May it be related width that?

Comment: I use `\iffalse ... \fi` for debugging.

Comment: @cacamailg However you do it. I usually comment blocks of code out. Occasionally, I move `\end{document}`. (I usually comment because I lose track less easily.) The point is, you have to find which bit it causing the issue. The error you are reporting is really, really common with PGF/TikZ. It might not even be an error in coding. It could just be reaching the limits. We just can't tell.

Comment: I got what was the problem. I had a counter to draw a progress bar. Something like `\pgfmathsetmacro{\progress}{360*\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}`. The problem comes from the `360*\insertframenumber` when `\insertframenumber` is at 45, which gives 360*45=16200, which I think is above some TeX limit. If I change the code to `\pgfmathsetmacro{\progress}{\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}\pgfmathsetmacro{\progress}{360*\progress}` everything works fine.

Comment: Ok. It is done now!

Answer (score 4):

I got what was the problem!

I had a counter to draw a progress bar. Something like `\pgfmathsetmacro{\progress}{360*\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}`. The problem comes from the `360*\insertframenumber` when `\insertframenumber` is at 45, which gives `360*45=16200`, which I think is above some TeX limit.

If I change the code to `\pgfmathsetmacro{\progress}{\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}\pgfmath‌​setmacro{\progress}{360*\progress}` everything works fine!

After doing this the same error "Dimensions too large!" occur. So more precisely, replace  `\pgfmathsetmacro{\progress}{360*\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}`  by  `\pgfmathsetmacro{\progress}{\insertframestartpage/\inserttotalframenumber}` and now it works... Thanks @cacamailg

Comment: I change the code from `\pgfmathsetmacro{\progress}{360*\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}` to  `\pgfmathsetmacro{\progress}{180*\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber + 180*\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}` and it works.

Comment: Does the above (180) solution simply move the slide limit to 90?